# Xcode - I can't run the whole methods from AppDelegate

Tags: objective-c, xcode, methods, url-scheme, appdelegate

I'm using custom URL schemes to open my app, then get the link and run in a method.  But I can't really run the method.

For example, I can't load web views or change labels or text fields.  So how do I load web views and change labels?

`AppDelegate.m`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {    
    if (!url) {  return NO; }
    NSString *URLopen= [[url host] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    vc.URLschemeLink = URLopen;
    [vc URLscheme];   
    return YES;
}
```

`ViewController.h`:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> {
    NSString *URLschemeLink;
}

-(void)URLscheme;

@end
```

`ViewController.m`:

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize URLschemeLink;

-(void)URLscheme {
    //for example:
    label.text = @"Hello"; //nothing will happen
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]]; //Nothing will happen

    NSLog ("Method Works Perfect"); //will happen

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Title:"
                                     message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", URLSchemeLink]
                                    delegate:nil
                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    //UIAlertView will work perfectly and show the URLschemeLink from AppDelegate.
}
```

ok How to load the label/webview anyway? 
i tested to pass a bool named runURLscheme (=true) from app delegate.
then i wrote in ViewDidLoad:

```
if(runURLscheme==true) {
    [self URLScheme];
}
```

but this will not work, it will not run the URLscheme method.
How can i load the labels/webviews anyway?

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: oh, yes. not a question sorry, but i said i cant load labels and web views, i'm gonna edit now

Comment: Is `application:handleOpenURL:` being called?

Comment: yes, look in my AppDelegate.m. but i have added a bool: vc.runURLscheme = another bool.

Comment: No, your `AppDelegate.m` shows that you have written the method.  It doesn't show that it is being called.  Have you put a logging statement or breakpoint there to confirm that the method is being called?

Comment: the method is not being called. but if i delete this code,(the code will look like my question) it will being called, but not loadtheview. How can i do for running my method correcly and able to set text to textfields?

Answer (score 0):

The main views associated with view controllers are generally lazy loaded.  Just because the view controller is initialised, it doesn't mean it's loaded its main view yet.  Your views are only safe to access once `viewDidLoad` has been called.

Generally speaking, this pattern works well:

- Store your data independently of any views that display it.
- When your custom URL scheme runs, update this data.
- Have a method on your view controller that updates its views from this data.
- Call this method from `viewDidLoad`.

If there's a chance this data will be updated after your views have already been loaded (e.g. if you are receiving data from the network), then use notifications or KVO to call your view updating method again.

Comment: i did something like this: - (void)viewDidLoad { if (runURLschemebool==true) { [self runmyURLSchemevoid}} it will not work.

Comment: can i do a pause or wait function to wait about 5 milliseconds to load the view then set textfields?

Comment: "Will not work" is not a helpful description.  What happens?  No, using a timer is a terrible idea.  iOS gives you exactly what you need to do this properly, there's no need for an unreliable hack like that.

Comment: Like I said "will not work" is not a helpful description.  Post the code and describe what happens.

Comment: when I pass the URLSchemelink to ViewController i'm also passing a bool named runURLschemebool (=true= then ViewDidLoas i put somethimg like,  
- (void)viewDidLoad { if (runURLschemebool==true) { [self runmyURLSchemevoid}} it will not work.What should i do?

Comment: Like I said: **post the code and describe what happens**.  "I put something like..." is not posting the code.  "It will not work" is not describing what happens.

Comment: i didn't put something like that, i put exactly like that. it will not work = my method will not run

Comment: No, you are paraphrasing your code.  Update your question and put **the code you are using exactly** into it.  Then describe the behaviour you are seeing.  *"It doesn't work"* is useless for diagnosing the problem.

Comment: And read this: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: done. my question is updated, i wanted to know the answer fast as possible so i didn't write a good question. sry